# Check if browser tab with a particular title already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I have several tabs in my browser...
How to check if a browser tab with a particular title already exists?

thanks.

Comment: all the tabs you opened is from your application only?

Comment: You need to read what it says on the tab, and see if you can spot duplicates. This is generally not something that is possible with javascript.

Comment: not all of them, one or more.

Comment: If it's just to check your own pages to see that the same page is'nt already open in another tab, you can do some trickery serverside to check what pages are open, and check ip adresses to find duplicates, but it's sounds like a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript in one tab cannot get any info from another tabs.

Otherwise it would be too easy to steal private data and money.

Comment: actually, tabs in chrome or IE9 are separated processes - then it is about IPC...